# References: 'and' changed to et-sign (&) in name of a journal (in 'journal' field)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

There is a bib file that the journal name contains 'and'. The bib item definition just like:

```
@Article{powell1998,
Title                    = {Nonlinear numerical optimization with use of a           
hybrid Genetic Algorithm incorporating the Modified Powell method},
Author                   = {Okamoto, Masahiro and Nonaka, Taisuke and Ochiai, Shuichiro and Tominaga, Daisuke},
Journal                  = {Applied Mathematics and Computation},
Year                     = {1998},
Number                   = {1},
Pages                    = {63-72},
Volume                   = {91},

Owner                    = {neal},
Timestamp                = {2016.12.12}
}
```

But it appears just like:

[image: refernce]

I have tried used and or \&, but it still show as the same.

Comment: As a quick fix, try to enclose the `and` in braces, i.e. `{and}`; maybe it helps. For an analysis what's happening please post the complete code starting with `\documentclass` and up to `\end{document}`. There are several parameters throughout your document that may influence the appearance of the bibliography and that we need to know.

Comment: If you want more specific help, please show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) this is quite unusual behaviour and will be quite specific to your style.

Comment: @gernot thanks, your method works. I should had a try.

Comment: @gernot Do you want to write up an answer, or do you think there is a good duplicate?

Comment: Do you use BibTeX or biblatex? Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: Aside: Because "Powell" is a proper name, it *must not* be lowercased. (You'd never write "albert einstein" or "julius caesar", right?) In your screenshot, however, the name *is* lowercased inside the title field. To keep this from happening, encase the name in curly braces, i.e., enter it as `{Powell}`. By the way, if "Modified Powell" is an established technical term, then neither "Modified" nor "Powell" should be lowercased -- enter the term as `{Modified Powell}` in the `title` field.

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the `and` in braces, i.e. write `{and}` instead.

BiB(La)TeX usually does not touch those parts of bibliography fields that are 'protected' by braces (not counting the outermost braces if used instead of quotes to delimit the contents of the field).

Comment: The OP tagged his/her posting with "biblatex", not "bibtex". However, it's quite unclear what the OP actually did.

Comment: @Mico It is also not quite clear to me. I added `(La)`; now the explanation should cover both cases. Feel free to delete the explanation, or the whole answer. Not many people will find this posting anyway, since searching for "and" is not easy.

Comment: @gernot SHAME on me.  You are so right.  I deleted my comment.   Please forgive me.